# Remove time filter in a date exposed filter in a view

Tags: views

I have a view with a date field exposed filter but this date field in its content type configured to be date and time. Is there any way to make this exposed filter work only by date because now when I enter a date, didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can implement this functionality by choosing "**Is Between**" in exposed filters. It works only with **date**.
Because at time of node creation, it's asking for date and time both in "Authored On" section.
If still you want to implement, you will have to use any trick by using jquery and hiddem fields in background